# Retrieve the correct casing from a case-insensitive lookup

Tags: .net, data-structures, case-insensitive

In .net, what would be the best data structure to store a reference casing?

I'm searching for a data structure which could return the casing with which an entry was originally inserted. Something like this:

```
Store.Add("HeLLo") //Adds a key

if (Store.Contains("hEllO")) //returns true (case-insensitive lookup)
    Store.Retreive("hEllO")) //return HeLLo, as initially inserted.
```

I currently use a case-insensitive dictionary with keys equal to the values, but this feels ugly.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)

dic.Add("HeLLo", "HeLLo")
if (dic.ContainsKey("hEllO"))
    dic["hEllO"]
```

Comment: I know I should use TryGetValue here, I just separated both calls to make the example clearer ;)

Comment: The approach you post in here is good, I don't understand why you still feel it's ugly

Comment: Because it duplicates some information: every word is stored twice. Since I wasn't sure it was possible to do anything better, I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 0):

I could really not find any method to get the key from any collection as in C++ (where std::maps return an iterator on key/value pairs).

If you are ready to do some tricky work it is possible: implement your own StringComparer derived class (of course letting everything be implemented by StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase), initialize a member, say `m_key`, with the searched key before a retrieval and have the `Equals(a,b)` method log the compared value into a member `m_actualKey` when the base implementation returned true, keeping the `a` if it is not `m_key` else keeping `b`.

After a successful retrieval, there is always exactly one "`Equals(a,b)` returned 1" event, so you are guaranted to find the actual value in `m_actualKey`.
Note that if the dictionary is used from multiple thread, you'd have to synchronize the queries.